# Random String in Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, random

I am trying to play a random .wav file from the command line. The files are called 1.wav, 2.wav, .... 10.wav

I have created the following .sh script and given it the appropriate execution rights:

```
#!/bin/sh
rnd=$((1 + RANDOM % 10))
cmd="aplay -D default:CARD=Device ./$rnd.wav"
echo $cmd
```

and it always returns

```
aplay -D default:CARD=Device ./1.wav
```

What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Can't replicate](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SpicySandyUtilities). Works fine. Maybe the shell doesn't support `RANDOM`?  Change `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` and make sure you run bash. Try `echo $BASH_VERSION` from within the script.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks, `/bin/bash` was the problem! Brilliant!